# Sending key-value pairs payload to Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to send N amount of custom key-value pairs attached to a single Hit. That hit will have its own key category/action/label, but I'm after defining my own keys.

I'm trying to integrate Google Analytics to my application. I've followed all configuration steps and it works, but I'm trying to understand how event reporting works, and how can I send my own custom events off predefined key-value pairs.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("hello", "world");
myMap.put("liek", "turtles");
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker(token);
tracker.send(myMap);
```

which is unwelcomely received with a Logcat error.

```
W/GAv4﹕ Discarding hit. Missing hit type parameter: tid=world, a=504324093
```

I'm experimenting with other APIs like HitBuilders and set(), but none provides a clear key-value pair mapping.

Comment: I'm not complete sure of what you are trying to achieve. Maybe custom dimensions or variables can be of use for you.

Comment: I'm trying to send N amount of custom key-value pairs attached to a single Hit. That hit will have its own category/action/label, but I'm after defining my own categories.

Custom dimensions are limited to 20/200 that have to be predefined, and that won't fly for my arbitrary keys. What are variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Custom Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets). First you should [create a custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827) and then send it together with a screen/event hit.

Using your example, you should use it like this:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreen("Home Screen");

// Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
// Note that the value only needs to be sent once.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setCustomDimension(1, "world")
    .setCustomDimension(2, "turtles")
    .build()
);
```

Where dimension #1 would be [configured](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827) as a "hello dimension" and dimension #2 would be a "liek dimension". This is an example on a screen view, but the same could be accomplished with an event.

Comment: Custom dimensions are limited to 20/200 that have to be predefined, and that won't fly for my arbitrary keys coming from a serialized flattened json.

Comment: If there is no other way, I'll just give your answer as valid.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the old Analytics SDK, which I wouldn't recommend. Try to use the `v4` and follow the [Analytics SDK for Android manual](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events).

I am not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but custom event can be send using the `EventBuilder` like this:

```java
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
         .setCategory("your-category")
         .setAction("your-action")
         .setLabel("your-label")
         .build());
```

Comment: I'm using v4. Category, action or label are not arbitrary maps of key-value pairs, just individual strings.

Comment: I'm trying to send N amount of custom key-value pairs attached to a single Hit. That hit will have its own category/action/label, but I'm after defining my own categories.